# Constructing the power set of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Consider the set of Natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$, and a particular natural number, $n$.

Consider $A_n$ to be the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ whose size is $\leq n$.

Now as we take $n$ to infinity, does this $A_n$ become the power set of $\mathbb{N}$?

The answer should be NO since $A_n$ is countable for all $n$, whereas the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ is not countable. We also know that a countable union of all countable sets is countable, but the power set of natural numbers is not countable.

So is there some glitch in the above argument?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Which of your subsets $A_n$ contains $\Bbb N$, which is an element of $\mathscr P (\Bbb N)$?

Comment: With such a construction you won't get any infinite proper subsets of the natural numbers,  e.g. all the co-finite subsets of the naturals.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose by "take $n$ to infinity" you mean the set
$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n.$$
Indeed, this set is not the power set of $\mathbb{N}$. You can either (as you have done in your question) argue that this is a countable set where the power set is uncountable or you can see directly that the above union does not contain any infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ while the power set certainly does.

Comment: So the confusion is why are infinite subsets excluded in the limit of n going to infinity?

Comment: Well, it's not really a limit. By definition, $B\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ iff there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $B\in A_n$. Hence, $B$ must be a finite subset (with at most $n$ elements).

Comment: Doesn't the axiom of infinity use the same argument (union of finite sets) to construct the full set of natural numbers? If it works there, what goes wrong for set of subsets?

Comment: The axiom of infinity says that there is a set $S$ which contains the empty set and for each $x\in S$ we also have $x\cup\{x\}\in S$. It ensures that there is a set of natural numbers. It neither tells us anything about its power set nor about the sets $A_n$.

Comment: Right! Just realised that the axiom of power set has to be added as an additional axiom since a power set cannot be constructed using other axioms.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking along the lines of forming
$$A_{\infty} = \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n$$
then note that this is *not* the power set of $\mathbb N$. Instead, this is the collection of all *finite* subsets of $\mathbb N$, which is not the same set. For example, it doesn't include $\{2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots\}$.

Comment: Doesn't the axiom of infinity use the same argument (union of finite sets) to construct the full set of natural numbers? If it works there, what goes wrong for set of subsets?

Comment: You will only end up with a countable collection in the end. Why would you think it would be the collection of *all* subsets? If $S\in A_{\infty}$, then $S\in A_n$ for some $n$, which means $S$ is finite. Thus no infinite set belongs to the collection $A_{\infty}$.